# MariaDB: SQL query to return array of json objects and remove `\` from response

Tags: mysql, mariadb, json, array

I am creating a sql query for api response in `javascript`.

But i stuck on one part that is creating a `array of json objects` of same group.

I have checked with the [json_arrayagg](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_arrayagg/) and also [json_objectagg](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_objectagg/) but can not able to create an array of json objects.

Below is a sql query in which i have also tried with the `JSON_ARRAY` and `JSON_OBJECT` methods.

```
public async getProducts() {
  try {
  let productTbl = '`products`';
  let prodImgTbl = '`product_images_ids`';
  let productImg = '`product_images`';

  let query = `SELECT 
  ${productTbl}.id AS productId,
  GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT(
    "imageId", ${prodImgTbl}.id, 
    "imageUrl", ${productImg}.thumbnail_image
  ))) imageData,

  FROM ${productTbl} 
  JOIN ${prodImgTbl} ON ${prodImgTbl}.product_id = ${productTbl}.id
  JOIN ${productImg} ON ${productImg}.id = ${prodImgTbl}.product_image_id
  GROUP BY ${productTbl}.id `

  let records = await pool.query(query);
  return records
  } catch (error) {
  throw error;
  }
}
```

Using this query i am getting the result in postman as below which is adding the `\` to the each key and value.

```
this.productList = [
  {
    "productId": 3,
    "imageData": "[{\"imageId\": 17, \"imageUrl\": \"/assets/images/321/1/1/1/image.jpg\"}],[{\"imageId\": 18, \"imageUrl\": \"/assets/images/322/image.jpg\"}]",
  }
]
```

*So the result that i wanted to render is as below, so that i can loop through the records.*

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    productId: 3,
    imageData [
      {
        imageId: 18,
        imageUrl: /assets/images/321/image.jpg
      },
      {
        imageId: 17,
        imageUrl: /assets/images/322/image.jpg
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

P.S: MySQL version: 5.5.5-10.3.22-MariaDB

Question Update:

SQL Query run in the adminer tool

```
SELECT 
`products`.id AS productId,
GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT(
  "imageId", `product_images_ids`.id, 
  "imageUrl", `product_images`.thumbnail_image
))) imageData
FROM `products`
JOIN `product_images_ids` ON `product_images_ids`.campaign_id = `products`.id
JOIN `product_images` ON `product_images`.id = `product_images_ids`.product_image_id
GROUP BY `products`.id
```

And here is a result [screenshot](https://tinyurl.com/ydegk95j) that i am getting.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Here, we are not Javascript programmers (some may be or may have been) - we are DBA's and SQL programmers. Could you provide the query **as sent to the server** (say, using the `mysql` tool or MySQL Workbench or your tool of choice). If your SQL works using your database tool, then it's a Javascript problem and should be taken to StackOverflow - if it **doesn't** work, then it's on-topic here! BTW, your title is: MariaDB: SQL query to generate array of json objects using` - using **what**?

Comment: Hello sir, i have updated my question, can you please review ? And please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: *can not able to create an array of json objects.* Build separate objects in subquery/CTE (with more detailed grouping), build array in main query (with more wide grouping).

Comment: PS. Create a fiddle with some sample data, and provide the result for this data.

Comment: Can you please help me that how can i remove this \ forward slash from the response ?